# How would I create a React reusable component in this case?

Tags: reactjs

Well I don't know if I am allow to post a question like this which is obviously more generic. But I just wanted to clarify and understand more about React reusable components. I have a component which holds information to open modals, and to insert user input.

I wanted to create the same component - when it comes to the design - but instead of having inputs and modals I just wanted to display information.

Is it possible for me to use the same visual component with different purposes such as to Input data and Visualize data? How would I do that since the input and the modal component uses logic and its internal state to open modals and uses methods from its parent to handleInputData? how do I switch these functionalities?

Comment: I think the best way to do this would be to make some containing component and then one component that has inputs and modals and another that just displays data, then wrap each of these content components inside the containing components. Then use CSS to apply the same styles.

Comment: Modal can and should be generic reusable... You pass the data it needs to display (inputs for form or other text) via props...

Comment: The question is too broad. It would be more constructive it it contained your current component, simplified to some extend if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course. It's the core feature of React, the declarative composition of components.

For instance, let's say that you have a `Modal` component which handles the display of something on the screen, above other content. You can use the props to customize what it renders right?

Them, you will specialize that component with your different behaviours, like a form or displaying information.

Example (conceptually):

```
const Modal = ({ title, children }) => (
  <div className="modal">
    <h1>{ title }</h1>
    <div className="body">
      { children }
    </div>
  </div>
)

const FormModal = () => (
  <Modal title="What's your name?">
    <form>
       { /* your form here */ }
    </form>
  </Modal>
)

const AlertModal = () => (
  <Modal title="Something happened">
    { /* your information to display here */ }
  </Modal>
)
```